# Android EditText requestFocus

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to create to do items (radio button's) dynamically. So i create linear layout with horizontal orientation and push radioButton and editText to it, and i need to set focus on this EditText. I try to use method requestFocus() but in my case it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

````
btnToDo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout llNew= new LinearLayout(NewNote.this);
                llNew.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                RadioButton rbNew= new RadioButton(NewNote.this);
                rbNew.setPadding(10,0,10,0);

                //set radio button color:
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
                {
                    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                            new int[][]{
                                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                            },
                            new int[] {
                                    Color.BLACK //disabled
                                    ,Color.BLACK //enabled
                            }
                    );
                    rbNew.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);//set the color tint list
                    rbNew.invalidate(); //could not be necessary
                }

                final EditText edNew = new EditText(NewNote.this);
                edNew.setTypeface(typefaceDunkin);
                edNew.setTextSize(25);
                edNew.setText("Some text");
                edNew.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                edNew.requestFocus(); //HERE

                //cross text after click on radio button
                rbNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        edNew.setPaintFlags(edNew.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    }
                });

                llNew.addView(rbNew);
                llNew.addView(edNew);
                content.addView(llNew);
                scrollViewDown();
            }
        });```
````

Comment: Please give better explanation on how the results vary from the expected result.

Comment: In my opinion after adding radio button and textInput the cursor(focus) must be instantly indicate this textInput. It's alow user to write something right away. My problem is, that focus doesn't indicate EditText after creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these line after call requestFocus:

```
  edNew.requestFocus();
  InputMethodManager im= (InputMethodManager) 
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  im.showSoftInput(edNew, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```